# How to align different numbered formulas to the left

Tags: equations, align

How to align different numbered formulas to the left.like the picture:
[image]

How to align different formulas to the left and have different numbers. My code like this will only make it have a common number.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\gamma_{x} &=-i t^{\prime}\left(\lambda-\lambda^{-1}\right) \\
\gamma_{y} &=0 \\
\gamma_{z} &=\Delta-\lambda t-t \lambda^{-1}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Use into your `\documentclass` (missing) the option leqno and I suggest to use `t'` instead of `t^{\prime}`.

Answer (score 3):

To typeset displayed equations -- numbered or unnumbered -- close to the left-hand edge of the text block, be sure load the `amsmath` package and to specify the option `fleqn` (short for "flush-left equations", I suppose).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\gamma_{x} &= -i t'(\lambda-\lambda^{-1}) \\
\gamma_{y} &= 0 \\
\gamma_{z} &= \Delta-\lambda t-t \lambda^{-1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much. Now I delete my answer.